# UnicodeEncodeError for searchCursor

Tags: python, ascii, unicode

```
import arcpy
import csv
import glob, os
os.chdir("C:\\path\\folder")
fieldsource = "C:\\path\\sampleshp.shp"
fields = [r.name for r in arcpy.ListFields(fieldsource)]
csv_out = "C:\\path\\table.csv"
with open(csv_out, "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(fields)
    for file in glob.glob("*.shp"):
        in_shp = "C:\\path\\folder\\" + file
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_shp, fields) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                wr.writerow(row)
```

I have few thousand shapefiles with only a few rows in them. I want to export their table to a single csv file. The script works but it seems I have a character in some of the files that python(2.7) doesn't like:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\path\folder\table.py", line 20, in 
>       wr.writerow(row)
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

How can I exclude/change the character that creates the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because the `csv` module cannot handle unicode strings that you are trying to write as ASCII.

There are two approaches:

1. Use the [`.encode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245415/read-and-write-csv-files-including-unicode-with-python-2-7) method on all strings/unicodes you have in a tuple that you get from `da.SearchCursor)`:

Code:

```
import arcpy
import csv

fc = r'C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\Default.gdb\HomeAddresses'
fields = [r.name for r in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if r.required == False]

with open('addresses.txt', "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(fields)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, 'OBJECTID < 10') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row_updated = [i.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(i, (str,unicode)) else i for i in row]
            wr.writerow(row_updated)
```

2. Use Python module that can do that for you, such as [`unicodecsv`](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv).

Code:

```
import arcpy
import unicodecsv

fc = r'C:\GIS\Temp\ArcGISHomeFolder\Default.gdb\HomeAddresses'
fields = [r.name for r in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if r.required == False]

with open('addresses_unicodecsv.txt', "wb") as f:
    wr = unicodecsv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(fields)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, 'OBJECTID < 10') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:            
            wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I tried the unicodecsv method first and worked perfectly. Thank you